# update-grub does not detect windows although os-prober does

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, then windows 7, and then fixed grub with gparted livecd.

now i am in ubuntu, and when i type sudo update-grub, i don't see windows detected, i see that instead:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-031100-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-031100-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-54-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-54-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-14-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-14-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

when I do sudo os-prober though, I see that:

```
/dev/sda4:Windows 7 (loader):Windows:chain
```

Why I can't add Windows to my grub using sudo update-grub, and how can I add it to grub so that I select OS during booting time? for there reference, here's output from bootinfoscript: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6215476/

***BONUS QUESTION:*** here's the output of sudo fdisk-l. why windows partition is marked as boot partition, although ubuntu is the one which is booted up after all?

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3d7c8272

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1           16072      626807      305368   de  Dell Utility
/dev/sda2          626808     6927031     3150112    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3         6928384  1237176319   615123968   83  Linux
/dev/sda4   *  1237176320  1953523711   358173696    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: The Windows 7 partition is bootable. Grub is chaining to it. Consider it a handoff.

Comment: You could try boot repair as mentioned here: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/462910/grub-os-prober-doesnt-see-windows-8-1-partition)